# How to get values from dynamically created textbox's in another click event in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm adding dynamic text box's to my panel in page load event, But I'm not able to access text box's in button click event and it is showing panel controls count ZERO(0) in button click event. Please give me solution to access text box values in button click event .

Thanks in advise.

Comment: add some code sample, it is easy to diagnose the issue

Comment: The reason for this behavior is a result from adding the text box dynamically. You have to ensure that on each post back, you are re-adding the textbox controls back to the panel and make sure that they have the same ID value.

Answer (score 1):

Add your control in the Init function:

```
<div id="Parent" runat="server">
</div>
<asp:Button ID="btnTest" runat="server" Text="Get text" OnClick="btnTest_Click" />

protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox textInput = new TextBox();
    textInput.ID = "text1";
    textInput.Text = "Test";
    Parent.Controls.Add(textInput);
}

protected void btnTest_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Write((Parent.FindControl("text1") as TextBox).Text);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside the  EventHandler of the particular button 
insert this

```
    TextBox MyTextBox=new TextBox();
//Assigning the textbox ID name 
MyTextBox.ID = "name" +""+ ViewState["val"] + i;
MyTextBox.Width = 440;
MyTextBox.Height = 40;
MyTextBox.TextMode = TextBoxMode.MultiLine;
this.Controls.Add(MyTextBox);
```